# Euler method in c++; Values getting too big too fast

Tags: c++, simulation, physics, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

i am trying to solve the equation of motion for a particle with mass m attached to a spring with a spring constant k. Both are set to 1 however.
The algorithm looks like this:

[image]

My (attempted) solution, written in c++, looks like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

// Initialise file to write series of values in
std::ofstream output("Eulermethod.txt");

// Define Euler algorithm
void euler(double x_0, double v_0, double delta, double t_max) {
    double x_prev = x_0;
    double v_prev = v_0;
    double x_new, v_new;
    for (double t = 0; t < t_max; t = t + delta) {
        x_new = x_prev + t * v_prev;
        v_new = v_prev - t * x_prev;
        // Writes time, position and velocity into a csv file
        output << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << t << "," << x_prev << "," << v_prev << std::endl;
        x_prev = x_new;
        v_prev = v_new;
        // Breaks loop if values get to big
        if ((x_new != x_new) || (v_new != v_new) || (std::isinf(x_new) == true) || (std::isinf(v_new) == true)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize with user input 
    double x_0, v_0, t_max, delta;
    std::cout << "Initial position x0?: ";
    std::cin >> x_0;
    std::cout << "Intial velocity v0?: ";
    std::cin >> v_0;
    std::cout << "Up to what time t_max?: ";
    std::cin >> t_max;
    std::cout << "Step size delta?: ";
    std::cin >> delta;
    // Runs the function
    euler(x_0, v_0, delta, t_max);
}
```

I know that the solution will grow indefinitely but for smaller values of t it should resemble the analytical solution while growing slowly.
The values i get are blowing out of proportions after ca. 10 iterations and i can not find out why.
When i plot the position as a function of the time i get the plot below, which is obviously wrong.

[image]

Comment: Your multiplications by `t` should probably be by `delta` instead

Comment: You should modify your code to use directly the test data, or provide the test data so that your observations can be duplicated. // It sometimes helps if you "integrate" the time as an extra component with derivative constant 1. If there are clear discrepancies, the method step has some implementation error.

Comment: Are you sure about the condition (x_new != x_new) || (v_new != v_new) ??

Comment: You forgot to tell us the input parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation implementation is wrong. You are usint `t` instead of `dt`. Correct variant:

```
x_new = x_prev + delta * v_prev;
v_new = v_prev - delta * x_prev;
```

And a side note if you plan to develop your code further: common approach to implementation of ODE solver is to have a method with signature similar to

```
Output = solveOde(System, y0, t);
```

Where `System` is method that describes the ODE `dy/dx = f(x,t)`, e.g.

```
std::vector<double> yourSystem(std::vector<double> y, double /*t unused*/)
{
    return {y[1], -y[0]};
}
```

`y0` are initial conditions, and `t` is a time vector (delta is calculated internally). Take a look at [boost odeint](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html) or more compact and transparent [python documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

Comment: As implemented, this code solves tx" - x' + t³x = 0 and finds the trivial solution x = 0.